# Using opencmis-workbench with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, cmis, open-source

I'm looking for using [chemistry-opencmis-workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) tool to access a freshly installed SharePoint 2013 standard.

In my test site, I have activated the "Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer" in site's feature but I cannot connect with the workbench tool ...

Any idea about the needed connection information ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid the question is more targeted to the tool than to SharePoint, it could make it difficult for you to find the answer here. I would throw out a hook at the tools forums as well to increase the chances :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is frequently asked by SharePoint users, because SharePoint's default settings are rather different from the settings of most other ECM products.

In this case, I am pretty sure the solution is to select "NTLM" in the Authentication dialog of CMIS Workbench:

[image: CMIS Workbench authentication NTLM]

Another solution is to configure SharePoint to use "Basic Authentication" instead of NTLM/Kerberos authentication.

By the way, what CMIS URL are you using? *(remove the server name as it might be confidential)*

Comment: Hi, using NTLM authentication subsystem is a good way for me.
As you ask, connection informationURL : http[s]://<server_fqdn>/sites/<site_name>/_vti_bin/cmissoapwsdl.aspx , Binding : Web services, Username : <AD domain>\<username>, Password : ... you know, Authentication : NTLM
After that CMIS workbench give me on the bottm dialogbox part a list of all alaments that compose my site (document library, tasks list, calendar, etc, ...)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you'll probably want to use the Expert Login tab and select the `SharePoint 2013 AtomPub` selection to connect.

Comment: Interesting! Would you mind adding a screenshot to show what it should look like? Thanks a lot :-)